# Parsing Unknown Length Unicode Name

Tags: python-3.x, pyparsing

I've been pondering this problem for a little while and I can't seem to find a solution.

I'm using pyparsing to parse text files containing summaries of events. Each text file contains numerous events. Each event, after a couple lines of header info, lists multiple people and data about them, in the following format:

**word integer: username (integer word word word)**

1. **word** is static and always the same
2. **integer** is any int
3. **username** can be any unicode character, including symbols, and can also include whitespace

I can't seem to build a grammar that can handle all of these possibilities. It's getting stuck when parsing weird unicode characters as well as whitespace/symbols. Example 3 below is what stumped me.

## Examples:

hello 1: -fred,123 (100 hello stack overflow)

hello 2: my name is brent (250 hello stack overflow)

hello 3: äää + óóó (0 hello stack overflow)

Anyone have any tips?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the response. This is working like a charm but I'm running into the same issue again once I moved on to the very next part of my text file. Not sure if I should start a new question or just add on to this one.

I'm now trying to parse lines of the following variety:

username: action-name action-details
username action

## Example:

```
brent morrow: add 10 to 20

brent:morrow: walks

äää + óóó: stands

brent morrow has returned
```

All action-names and action-details are static and known.

So I'm running into an issue where I can't skip to the text beyond the username because it can be one of many different actions. It ends up just printing the entire text file (or at least a significant portion of it).

I'm absolutely stumped. I'm basically trying to figure out a way to look ahead, find the following:

colon + action-name + action details

or

whitespace + action

... and then take all of the characters (the username) before that. But action-name/action-details/action can be one of many from a predefined list of actions. Negative lookahead, ~, looks promising but I can't seem to find a solution to accepting all unicode characters for the username.

The text files being parsed are from a third party outside of my control so it's impossible to find a way to structure the source files more concretely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `SkipTo` (code uses latest pyparsing 2.1.4 runtests features):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

tests = """
    # a regular line
    hello 1: -fred,123 (100 hello stack overflow)

    # a username with spaces
    hello 2: my name is brent (250 hello stack overflow)

    # a username with non-ASCII
    hello 3: äää + óóó (0 hello stack overflow)
"""

from pyparsing import *

COLON,LPAR,RPAR = map(Suppress, ":()")
integer = pyparsing_common.integer

leading = "hello" + integer + COLON
trailing = LPAR + integer + "hello" + "stack" + "overflow" + RPAR

strip = lambda t: t[0].strip()
line = leading + SkipTo(trailing).setParseAction(strip) + trailing

line.runTests(tests)
```

Gives:

```
# a regular line
hello 1: -fred,123 (100 hello stack overflow)
['hello', 1, '-fred,123', 100, 'hello', 'stack', 'overflow']

# a username with spaces
hello 2: my name is brent (250 hello stack overflow)
['hello', 2, 'my name is brent', 250, 'hello', 'stack', 'overflow']

# a username with non-ASCII
hello 3: äää + óóó (0 hello stack overflow)
['hello', 3, '\xe4\xe4\xe4 + \xf3\xf3\xf3', 0, 'hello', 'stack', 'overflow']
```

Exercise for the OP: add results names to the integers and username to make accessing the parsed fields easier.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That worked like a charm. Thanks for point out results name as well, that will be very useful. I'm about to add another issue I ran into immediately after implementing this solution. Not sure if I should open another question but it's relevant to this one so I'll stay here for now.